# If I am added as a collaborator to a GitHub repository, how can I get it to show on my profile?

Tags: github

I was added as a collaborator to a GitHub repository. I received an email about it and everything, but it doesn't appear on my "Repositories" list when I go to my profile.

Is there a reason for this and is it possible to get it to show on that list so I don't have to keep finding the link in my email to go to it?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully by now you've found an answer, but for anyone else with the same question, it won't show in your "Repositories" list, because that's only the repositories where you are an author/owner.  However, on the left side of [the main GitHub page](https://github.com/) (when you're logged in) you'll see a sidebar titled "**Repositories**".

This list is where you will see all repositories that you contribute to, or have forked.

Comment: hmmm  this is not true anymore. I cannot see repos that I am added as a collaborator. The only way to see it is on: https://github.com/settings/repositories

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C this actually works for me, but is kinda dumb. there should be a tab for these repos in your profile next to the repos you own. maybe someone in github will implement such a thing in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I have found thus far: Star the repository you are a collaborator on.

This will now show up in the Stars tab on your profile page. I don't have very many repositories starred, but apparently there is a new beta feature called Lists. You could star it and then put it in a list called 'Collaborator' or something like that.